# Upload image, create its thumb then save

Tags: php, image, image-manipulation, thumbnails

Let's say I uploaded an image. I can get its temp directory, then save it with `move_uploaded_file()` but what if I wanted to also create a thumb and save both in some folder?

I know how to save the uploaded image, but I don't know how to start manipulating an image and save it after creating a thumb.

Comment: You don't need to put '[PHP]' in a title, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use Verot PHP Upload class and always had success with it. This PHP class is really simple to implement and can manipulate a image any way you want. It can save the image also in the specified folder.

You can download it from [here](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm)

To view demos and easy documentation of the Upload class visit http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm?PHPSESSID=5375147e959625e56e0127f3458a6385

Below is a simple sample I got from the website

```
//How to use it?
//Create a simple HTML file, with a form such as:

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
   <input type="file" size="32" name="image_field" value="">
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload">
 </form>

//Create a file called upload.php:

  $handle = new upload($_FILES['image_field']);
  if ($handle->uploaded) {
      $handle->file_new_name_body   = 'image_resized';
      $handle->image_resize         = true;
      $handle->image_x              = 100;
      $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
      $handle->process('/home/user/files/');
      if ($handle->processed) {
          echo 'image resized';
          $handle->clean();
      } else {
          echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
      }
  }

//How to process local files?
//Use the class as following, the rest being the same as above:

  $handle = new upload('/home/user/myfile.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

The GD library makes this super-easy.

You will want to calculate the dimensions of your original image so that you preserve your aspect ratio, then it's just a case of resampling the image in a smaller size. Here is a good tutorial that clearly explains everything: http://www.phptoys.com/e107_plugins/content/content.php?content.46

Answer (score 1):

you need either [php gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). here is a quick example of resizing using gd(from the manual):

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb, 'thumbs/thumb1.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: How do I save the image in some folder instead of displaying it?

Comment: the second parameter of the imagejpeg function is the filename. i've updated the example. also, check out the man page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

Use Image magick. 
check previous posts on stack overflow
[Imagemagick thumbnail generation with php - using -crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679092/imagemagick-thumbnail-generation-with-php-using-crop)
[PHP: Creating cropped thumbnails of images, problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670386/php-creating-cropped-thumbnails-of-images-problems)
[Image processing class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039144/image-processing-class-in-php)
http://www.imagemagick.org/

```
define('THUMB_WIDTH', 60);
define('THUMB_HEIGHT', 80);
define('MAGICK_PATH','/usr/local/bin/');

function makeThumbnail($in, $out) {
    $width = THUMB_WIDTH;
    $height = THUMB_HEIGHT;
    list($w,$h) = getimagesize($in);

    $thumbRatio = $width/$height;
    $inRatio = $w/$h;
    $isLandscape = $inRatio > $thumbRatio;

    $size = ($isLandscape ? '1000x'.$height : $width.'x1000');
    $xoff = ($isLandscape ? floor((($inRatio*$height)-$width)/2) : 0);
    $command = MAGICK_PATH."convert $in -resize $size -crop {$width}x{$height}+{$xoff}+0 ".
        "-colorspace RGB -strip -quality 90 $out";

    exec($command);
}
```